# Unable to handle disable check box

Tags: jquery, html

my html:

```
<div class="check">
<input class="sfCheckbox" type="checkbox" title="view" disabled="true" checked="checked">
<input class="sfCheckbox" type="checkbox" title="view" checked="checked">
</div>
```

in jquery i try:

```
$('.check .sfCheckbox').attr('checked', false);
```

code work fine but i want to `('checked', false)` if check box is not disable.How to get desire result.Thanks.

i mean if check box is disable do nothing .if not 'checked', false.Thanks.

Comment: check is the class name of a div. how are setting its attribute checked as false

Comment: Your jquery snippet is selecting a div, but you're trying to set a checked attribute on it? I assume you want to set the attribute on one of the inputs, not the div, in which case use .prop, not .attr

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Your current code checks wheter or not the check div (not any checkbox) has the 'checked' attr. I can't imagine this is what you intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Adding a `.not('[disabled]')` in your statement will do the trick

```
$('.check .sfCheckbox').not('[disabled]').attr('checked', false);
```

This statement will uncheck all `'enabled'` check boxes with class `sfCheckbox` that are inside an element with class `check`

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery 1.6 or higher, don't use `.attr()` anymore, there is `.prop()` instead:

```
$('selector goes here').prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if(!$(".check").is(":disabled")) {
 $(this).attr('checked', false);

}
```

Comment: i want opposite side of above code.if check box is disable do nothing .if not `'checked', false`.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/rc9HG/).
The explaination is that with $('.check') you are getting the div element and not the checkboxes. You havo to provide checkboxes selectors to achieve what you wanto

Answer (score 1):

Working code:

```
if($("input").attr("disabled")==undefined)
        $('input').removeAttr('checked','checked');
```