# Enabling disabled CheckBoxList in javascript - checked items not recognized after postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have a CheckBoxList which can load as disabled, but might need to become enabled after some client side actions.

I am able to enable the checkboxes using jQuery, but the problem is that after submitting the page, the selected items in the ChceckBoxList are not recognized (probably because the control is not in the ViewState).

A simple example for the scenario:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkList1" runat="server" Enabled="false" ClientIDMode="Static">
       <asp:ListItem Value="123" />
       <asp:ListItem Value="456" />
       <asp:ListItem Value="789" />
</asp:CheckBoxList>

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#divEnable").click(function()
    {
        var inputs = $("#chkList1").find("input");
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
        {
            inputs[i].disabled = false;
        }
    });
}
```

And then after enabling the checkboxes, selecting them and sending a postback - no selected items are recognized.

I tried disabling the items "manually", as in

```
chkList1.Items[0].Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
```

But that did not work (the `disabled` attribute was attached to the containing span instead of the input control).

I also considered using hidden fields to keep track of the checkbox selections, but since I have multiple CheckBoxLists in a grid, that would be very inelegant.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: You should show the HTML that is generated and ends up in the browser, not the ASP that creates it.

Comment: It's just a table where each row contains a checkbox input and a corresponding label within a span. When `Enabled="False"`, the inputs have `disabled="disabled"`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#divEnable").click(function()
    {
        var inputs = $("#chkList1").find("input")
            .each(function(){
                            //if($(this).is(":disabled"))
                            //{
                               $(this).prop("disabled",true);
                            //}
                          });      
});
```

Ref:
[jQuery asp control .prop(“disabled”, “”) not enabling check box in IE 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109938/jquery-asp-control-propdisabled-not-enabling-check-box-in-ie-9)
[Unable to handle disable check box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654894/unable-to-handle-disable-check-box)

Comment: I think it should be `$(this).prop("disabled",false)`.
Anyway, my problem is not enabling the checkboxes (they're clickable after my click event executes), but the fact that the selected items are not recognized in the server side after a postback. I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
  for (i = 0; i < document.forms[0].length; i++)
   {
      e = document.forms[0].elements[i];
      if (e.id.indexOf("chklist") != -1)
      {
           e.disabled = false;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The way I fixed this was to enable the checkboxlist to start, then on load of the page, disable using script. That way the controls got into the viewstate, but were still disabled to start.

```
    var checkBoxListToChange = document.getElementById('');
    var checkboxes = checkBoxListToChange.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var x = 0; x < checkboxes.length; x++) {
        checkboxes[x].disabled = true;
    }
```